# How to concatenate jq with variables?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have a json object I am reading with jq and trying to write some properties with local variables.

I am setting local variable in my shell script like so:

```
LOCATION_NAME="stag5"
DOMAIN_LOCATION="example.io"
```

I am then building out the following variable:

```
echo "Build New ID"

DOMAIN_NAME_BUILT="$LOCATION_NAME.$DOMAIN_LOCATION.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
```

I am trying to read my `distconfig.json` file and set the properties with the above variables.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
jq '.Origins.Items[0].DomainName = "$DOMAIN_NAME_BUILT"' distconfig.json > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" distconfig.json
```

The command is working, but it is passing in the variable as a string to my new json file. 
So when I view the property in the new created json file it is being saved as `"$DOMAIN_NAME_BUILT"` instead of `stag5.example.io.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`

How can I instead of passing the string pass the variable for $DOMAIN_NAME_BUILT and write it to the new json file

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with concatenation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--argjson` option instead of parameter interpolation.

```
jq --argjson dnb "$DOMAIN_NAME_BUILT" \
    '.Origins.Items[0].DomainName = $dnb' distconfig.json > "$tmp" &&
  mv "$tmp" distconfig.json
```

(Your immediate issue is that parameter expansion doesn't occur inside single quotes, but building a static filter that takes an argument is safer than building a filter dynamically.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This makes much more sense looking at it, I wasn't sure the syntax for the argjson.. however, entering your answer is returning `jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson`

Comment: I got it working! Thanks for your answer. The solution was to replace `--argjson` with `--arg` in your answer.
Do you know how I would go about setting another 2 variables? Would I just copy and repeat the block below?

Comment: I always get `--arg` and `--argjson` confused. You can use either option multiple times in a single call to `jq`, and the assignment filters can be piped. `jq ... 'x1 = y1 | x2 = y2`, e.g.

Comment: Something like this is ok? 

```jq --arg dnb "$DOMAIN_NAME_BUILT" \ --arg id "$DOMAIN_ID_BUILT" \
    '.Origins.Items[0].DomainName = $dnb' | '.Origins.Items[0].Id = $id' distconfig.json > "$tmp" &&
  mv "$tmp" distconfig.json```

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: It's not giving me an error but not finishing the script, not sure what it doesn't like about the syntax?

Comment: Sorry, the typo in my first comment made it unclear where the pipe should be. It's an internal `jq` pipe, not a shell pipe: `jq ... 'x1 = y1 | x2 = y2' distconfig.json`.